# How do I enable LastPass (or any other browser add-on) for a pinned site in Internet Exploer 9, 10, or 11?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, browser-addons, windows-8.1, lastpass

I use LastPass for several websites, and in all my browsers I can enable the LastPass toolbar to simplify logging into a website:

[image: ie11 with lastpass]

I also have some pinned sites in IE11.  When I open a pinned site all the third-party toolbars, including LastPass, seem to be disabled and hidden from the options:

[image: ie11 pinned site--can't enable lastpass]

As you can see in the following screenshot, LastPass is installed and enabled for both 32-bit and 64-bit IE:

[image: add-ons]

I've observed the same problem in IE9 and IE10 on Windows 7 and in IE11 on Windows 8.1.  In all cases, I'm running the default IE on 64-bit Windows.  How do I enable the LastPass toolbar for a pinned site?

Comment: When you launched this pinned sites are you using the Desktop or ModernUI version of IE.  Also are we talking about Windows 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: If it was clear it was the destop version I wouldn't have asked.  Which browser is being launched IE 32-bit or IE 64-bit when you launch a pinned website?

Comment: You said you were using Windows 8 hence my question. I use Windows 8 on several machines. Are you sure IE x64 is being launched in all cases that is NOT the default behavior. How did you verify it was being launched? Have you tried going back to the default behavior? I am highly suspect that the 64-bit browser doesn't have the extensions installed.  Lets humor me, visit https://lastpass.com/dl  on both IE-32bit and IE-64bit

Comment: @Ramhound I appreciate your effort but your questions just confused the issue in this case. I originally stated that I have the same issue on both Windows 7 and 8. Win7 doesn't have ModernUI, and nobody who has used ModernUI can legitimately mistake my screenshots for ModernUI. You're correct it was 32-bit IE, but as my new screenshot shows, LastPass is installed for both 32- and 64-bit. Your lastpass.com/dl suggestion is also misleading because it returns the 64-bit installer on 64-bit Windows regardless of the browser architecture. But all this is irrelevant as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling browser add-ons for pinned sites was an user experience design decision:

> [The reason Add-ons don't run on pinned sites is that we wanted to
>   remove any non-site specific extension points (like toolbars and BHOs)
>   from altering the original browsing experience created by the
>   site.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/17/user-experiences-customizing-pinned-sites.aspx)